# Unable to insert data to database using textinput value

Tags: database, react-native, sql-insert, textinput

I want to insert data retrieved from textinput and store it into database table.

I tried passing the textinput value as this.state.text1,but it does not insert and no action is perfomed

```
sync (){
   console.log('inside sync function');
  const { value1 } = this.state.text1;
    console.log('value1 is' +this.state.text1 );
   db.transaction(function(txn) {
    txn.executeSql(
      "INSERT INTO " +
        localDB.tableName.tblLogin +
        " (text1,text2) VALUES (:text1,:text2)",
      [
         +this.state.text1,
        "native3"
      ]
    );
  });
  console.log('insert values success');
  console.log(this.state.text1);
  console.log(this.state.text2);

 }
```

Expected result:The textinput value should be inserted to the table inside database

Actual result:No value is inserted to database.It shows NULL in the database when queried.

Comment: what is your console result.  i.e.  `console.log('value1 is' +this.state.text1 )` .. what is in console

Comment: I am getting the textinput value correctly but when its in the query insert into like shown,it is giving NULL in the table

Comment: Are you sure the query string is being interpreted correctly? Try hard coding the query string. Is the database adding the value then?

Comment: yes when hardcoded it is taking the value

Comment: Try this, put your query string in a string template variable, like this, let query = `INSERT INTO ${localDB.tableName.tblLogin} ..etc.` (make sure to use the tilde character) then print that to the console. Compare both strings, the hard-coded that works, and your prepared query variable. Sometimes databases need "INSERT INTO `table_name'.." not "INSERT INTO table_name"

Comment: I didnt get u.Could you tell me based on above query?

Comment: Sorry the `(tilde) character is not showing up. I'm talking about a template literal. It's a way of formatting a string. Here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Your Query as

```
async sync  = () => {

  console.log('inside sync function');
  console.log('text1 is' + this.state.text1 );

  await db.transaction((txn) => {

    txn.executeSql(
        `INSERT INTO ${localDB.tableName.tblLogin}(text1,text2) VALUES (?,?)`,
        [this.state.text1,"native3"], 
        (r) => {console.log("success" , r);},
        (error) => {console.log("error is", error);}
    );

 });

  console.log('insert values success');
  console.log(this.state.text1);

}
```

Comment: I tried this but no rows added to the table and no error

Comment: Updated my answer , please tell corresponding console message.

Comment: It did not go into any of the success or error console.This variable r didn't have any effect

Comment: please try updated provided sync function. What is your all console result

Answer (score 0):

Try delaying the insert by 1 second using `setTimeout(() =>`. React's `this.setState` is not instant.

```
sync (){
   console.log('inside sync function');
  const { value1 } = this.state.text1;
    console.log('value1 is' +this.state.text1 );

   setTimeout(() => {
       db.transaction(function(txn) {
       txn.executeSql(
         "INSERT INTO " +
           localDB.tableName.tblLogin +
           " (text1,text2) VALUES (:text1,:text2)",
         [
            +this.state.text1,
           "native3"
         ]
        );
       });
   }, 1000);

  console.log('insert values success');
  console.log(this.state.text1);
  console.log(this.state.text2);

 }
```